# How to access UITableIndexView (section index view) of UITableView? e.g. tableView.sectionIndexView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to access UITableIndexView (section index view) of UITableView? e.g. tableView.sectionIndexView

Is it in any ways possible to access it?

[image]

Comment: do you want to find out some view in a particular section and a  particular row?

Comment: @priya No, added screenshot

Comment: @DiasDosymbaev You can try this code-> https://github.com/gdavis/GDIIndexBar and https://github.com/mindz-eye/MYTableViewIndex

Comment: @dahiya_boy thanks!